# How to replace following script to search for values and not strings?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have the following macro which iterates though each cell in a specified column. If the cell contains a value of the string `#VALUE!`, it is replaced by the average of 2 cells above and below it (which contain integers).

```
Sub Checker()
Dim Qty As Range

For Each Qty In Range("A1:A5").Cells

    If InStr(1, (Qty.Text), "#VALUE!") Then
    Qty.FormulaR1C1 = "=AVERAGE(R[-2]C:R[-1]C,R[1]C:R[2]C)"

    End If
Next
End Sub
```

So:

```
  A                  A
1  10              1  10
2  10              2  10
3  #VALUE!   ->    3  10
4  10              4  10
5  10              5  10
```

Now I would like the macro to search for `0` instead of `#VALUE!`.

```
  A                  A
1  10              1  10
2  10              2  10
3   0        ->    3  10
4  10              4  10
5  10              5  10
```

What would I need to replace in the code?

Simply replacing `"#VALUE!"` to `"0"` doesn't work. My guess is to use another function instead of `InStr` but I am not very familiar with VBA.

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work"? What does the code do, what do you expect?

Comment: @Dave - Thanks buddy, made an edit. Yes, I meant `"0"` and removed `Set wks = ActiveSheet` as it was unnecessary.

Comment: One option would be to check if the value is 0, if not, then use Moduls 10 and check if the remainder is 0, if it is then you can act accordingly

Comment: @Dave - Thanks again, I will take a look at using Moduls 10. In the dataset I am using, there are annoying `*` symbols which come before `#VALUE!` like `*#VALUE!` (this is not my dataset so not sure how they got there). Hence why I used `InStr`.

Comment: If you need to check for either, you may also want to consider IsNumeric() http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/isnumeric.php

Comment: @Dave - That's billiant! Many thanks for mentioning that function, this actually simplifies other pieces of code that I use :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If InStr(1, (Qty.Text), "0") Then
```

will check if there is a "0" anywhere in the string which might not be what you want. Try

```
If Qty.Text = "0" Then
```

or

```
If StrComp(Qty.Text, "0") = 0 Then
```

for checking if the complete string is "0".

Comparing the complete string would have also been a better solution for the "#VALUE!" check.

Comment: Thank you! I have incorporated the string comparison method for both values and to check for `"#VALUE!"` =)